# Efecto de apagado en una imagen con Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, slider

tengo un slideshow el caso es que las imágenes son muy brillantes y lo que necesito es que cuando cargue una imagen a los segundos, justo antes que aparezca el texto se coloque un fondo encima de la imagen como un `background`, lo hice pero quiero hacerlo en segundos intente con `animate` de `jquery`, y `transition` de `css` pero no logro hacerlo acá les mando el código

```js
if(g.hasClass("slider_thumbs")){ // Esta haciendo el cambio de imagen
var k=$j("div.item").index($j("div.item.active")[0])+1 // Para saber cuando cambia de imagen en el slider 
$j("div.item.active").addClass("element_hovered"); 
}
```

```html
<div id="image_1" class="image" style="
                        background-image: 
                        linear-gradient(
                          rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3),
                          rgba(253, 249, 249, 0.3)
                        ),
         url(img/widget3/Widget-3.jpg); background-  size:cover">
   </div>
```

El código `javascript` digamos que es el código que utiliza apenas cambie de imagen, por lo que ahí podría hacer la modificación el tema es que el `div` esta perfecto porque tiene un fondo negro y se aprecia las letras, pero lo que necesito es que ese fondo se coloque en segundos, no al instante, es decir quiero que el Linear-gradient funcione a los segundos de haber cargado dicha imagen

Comment: creo que seria mas sencillo hacerlo solo con css

Comment: Pues, necesito que el css pase despues de que cargue la imagen, asi que alguna idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creo que entendí que quieres lograr, puedes pasar ese gradiente a un seudoelemento, en este caso puede ser: `before` y le añades a este ultimo la animación para que aparezca después de 0.3s de que aparezca la imagen. Ejemplo:

```js
if(g.hasClass("slider_thumbs")){ // Esta haciendo el cambio de imagen
var k=$j("div.item").index($j("div.item.active")[0])+1 // Para saber cuando cambia de imagen en el slider 
$j("div.item.active").addClass("element_hovered"); 
}
```

```css
body{margin: 0;}

.image{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background-image: url(http://picsum.photos/1200/900); 
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  position: relative;
}

.image::before{
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  background-image: 
    linear-gradient(
      rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5),
      rgba(253, 249, 249, 0.5)
  );
  opacity: 0;
  animation: aparecer ease 1s both .3s;
}

@keyframes aparecer{
  to { opacity: 1;} 
}
```

```html
<div id="image_1" class="image">
   </div>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias Edgar, eso era  lo que estaba buscando exactamente

Answer (score 0):

```css
 .image {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  position: relative;
 }
 .image img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
 }
 .image p {
  bottom: 0;
  padding: 20px 0;
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .7);
  color: #fff;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
 }
 .image:hover > p {
  opacity: 1;
 }
```

```html
<div class="image">
 <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1508182390781-8dd476c3237c?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&s=eeb978f1ebd12334e7b08117fcaad01d&auto=format&fit=crop&w=751&q=80" alt="Image Numero 1">
 <p>image numero 1</p>
</div>
```

Te dejo un ejemplo de como puedes hacerlo

Comment: Hola Eddy, las publicaciones que son sólo código se consideran de baja calidad. Por favor, añade una pequeña descripción con lo que has hecho y por qué funciona. Lee [answer] para más información y consejos.